# Elastic Search Sorting Dylema

Tags: elasticsearch

For My Elastic Search I have following parameters

- BookName :`\"type\":\"string\`
- IsFeaturedBook : `\"type\":\"string\"` (But saves True or False)
- IsSoldOutBook : `\"type\":\"boolean\",\"index\":\"no\",\"include_in_all\": false` (saves True or False)

Following Query :

```
"sort" :[{ "BookName" : {"order" : "asc"}}]
```

Sorts Package Name in Ascending Order

---

Following Query:

```
"sort" :[{ "IsFeaturedBook" : {"order" : "asc"}}]
```

or

```
"sort" :[{ "IsFeaturedBook" : "asc"}]
```

Sorts IsFeaturedBook , since its type is string

---

However the boolean type IsSoldOutBook, is not able to sort with any of the following queries, I suspect its because of boolean type,

```
"sort" :[{ "IsSoldOutBook" : {"order" : "asc"}}]
```

or

```
"sort" :[{ "IsSoldOutBook" : "asc"}].
```

Please let me know How could I achieve this?. Secondly is there any difference between `{ "IsFeaturedBook" : {"order" : "asc"}` and `{ "IsFeaturedBook" : "asc"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is `"index": "no"`. Elasticsearch tries to sort by that field, however if it's not indexed, it sorts by `null` value.

See this reproduction:

```
DELETE /test

PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "sample": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "index": "no"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/sample/1
{ "field": true }
PUT /test/sample/2
{ "field": false }
PUT /test/sample/3
{ "field": true }
```

Let's run this query:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "field": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So now when you're trying to sort by `field`, it will pick `null` values and since they're all equal - there's not going to be any impact. This is a result from query above.

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "field": true
        },
        "sort": [
          null
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "field": false
        },
        "sort": [
          null
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "field": true
        },
        "sort": [
          null
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In order to fix that, remove `"index": "no"` from your properties. I've tried that by myself and it worked just fine. Then you'll see `"sort": "T"` or `"sort": "F"`, which will do job fine.

Comment: Thank You so much :) Let's see why it is so... Then I hope there is no issue even after it has a null value in it it will sort?

Comment: @TBA Shouldn't be. Just remove `"index": "no"` from your field properties and that's it. And don't forget to reindex data.